# How do I change the color of the header with JavaScript (I am using innerHTML) without changing the text as well?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I use the select menu and select the color purple for example. I want the color of the header to change to that color but I do not want the text to change. The innerHTML is changing both the text and the color. How do I go about solving this issue?

```
#header {
color: green;
    }
#list {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

.purple-color{
     color: purple;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="header">Header</h1>
    <!--Change Value of Header with Input Field-->
<div>
 Name:<input type="text" id="my-text" value="">
<p>Click the button to change the value of the header.</p>
<button onclick="onChange('header')">Click Me</button>
</div>

    <!-- Select Size Menu-->
<div class= "select-menu">
    <label for="header-color">Color:</label>

    <select name="select-menu" id = "list" onchange="changeColor()" >
    <option value="purple">Purple</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <script>
      function changeColor(){
          const color = document.getElementById("header");
          const selectColor = document.getElementById('list').value;
    

         if (selectColor === "purple") {
             color.innerHTML = selectColor;
             color.style = 'color: #F00';
         }
         else if (selectColor === "blue") {
            color.innerHTML = selectColor;
            color.style = 'color: #F00';
         }

         else if (selectColor === "green") {
            color.innerHTML = selectColor;
            color.style = 'color: #F00';
         }
        
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: just remove all `color.innerHTML = selectColor;`?

Comment: But then then the color wont change

Comment: the line below it changes the color.

Comment: I think `background-color: #F00` is what you're looking for, is it not?

Comment: O wow I feel dumb haha

Answer (score 0):

Setting [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) replaces the HTML content of the element, in your case its text. Just use `color.style.color` alone.  Note that I've used `color.style.color`, and not `color.style` - you were reassigning the entire style object to a string!

```js
function changeColor() {
  const color = document.getElementById("header");
  const selectColor = document.getElementById('list').value;


  if (selectColor === "purple") {
    // color.innerHTML = selectColor;
    color.style.color = selectColor
  } else if (selectColor === "blue") {
    // color.innerHTML = selectColor;
    color.style.color = selectColor;
  } else if (selectColor === "green") {
    // color.innerHTML = selectColor;
    color.style.color = selectColor;
  }

}
```

```css
#header {
  color: green;
}

#list {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.purple-color {
  color: purple;
}

</style></head><body>
```

```html
<h1 id="header">Header</h1>
<!--Change Value of Header with Input Field-->
<div>
  Name:<input type="text" id="my-text" value="">
  <p>Click the button to change the color of the header.</p>
  <button onclick="changeColor()">Click Me</button>
</div>

<!-- Select Size Menu-->
<div class="select-menu">
  <label for="header-color">Color:</label>

  <select name="select-menu" id="list" onchange="changeColor()">
    <option value="purple">Purple</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Your confusion here may be a good reminder to be careful what you name things. Why not name the header element `header` or something similar? That way when people read your code, they'll see something a little more indicative of what's happening, as in `header.style.color = "purple"` rather than something kind of confusing like `color.style.color = "purple"`.

Comment: OP was looking for `background-color` to make the background change, as `color` changes the color of the text, which was not the desired functionality

Comment: Oh, I must have missed that (the question indicates "color of the header"). Surely the main conceptual problem is that OP is assigning a string to the style object anyway?

Comment: The style attribute can be assigned to a string just like any other attribute like id, class, onClick, etc. It's the equivalent of `<div style="..." ></div>`. The style attribute itself is not an object, although there is an interface to act like it is to make interaction with individual properties much easier.

Comment: Ah, [TIL!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#setting_styles) Still seems that the other way is preferable, but good to know, thanks!

Comment: Yes agree, just wanted to point it out that it was not the source of the OP's issue. What they did was fine, it was just the fact that they were setting the wrong CSS property to get their desired result.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably more efficient to have the form values be the colors you want to set. Then you can just have your `changeColor()` function set the color according to `selectColor`. Setting the text color should be done with `color.style.color`, not `color.style`.

Further, the `changeColor()` function shouldn't be changing the `innerHTML` of the header. It seems, from your comments, that this should be done in response to clicking the Click Me button.

This code should do what you want:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #header {
                color: green;
            }
            #list {
                margin-top: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1 id="header">Header</h1>
            <!--Change Value of Header with Input Field-->

        <div>
            Name:<input type="text" id="my-text" value="">
            <p>Click the button to change the value of the header.</p>
            <button onclick="changeText('header')">Click Me</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Select Size Menu-->
        <div class= "select-menu">
            <label for="header-color">Color:</label>

            <select name="select-menu" id = "list" onchange="changeColor()" >
                <option value="purple">Purple</option>
                <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                <option value="green">Green</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    
    <script>
        function changeColor(){
            const color = document.getElementById("header");
            const selectColor = document.getElementById("list").value;
            color.style.color = selectColor;
            
        }

        function changeText(id) {
            const elem = document.getElementById(id);
            const text = document.getElementById("my-text").value;
            elem.innerHTML = text;
        }
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The script tag after modification:

```
<script>
    function changeColor(){
        const color = document.getElementById("header");
        const selectColor = document.getElementById('list').value;

       if (selectColor === "purple") {
          color.setAttribute('style', 'color: purple')
       }
       else if (selectColor === "blue") {
          color.setAttribute('style', 'color: blue')
       }

       else if (selectColor === "green") {
          color.setAttribute('style', 'color: green')
       }

       // You can also use something like this
       // color.setAttribute('style', `color: ${selectColor}`); // selectColor has to be a valid css color value
      
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).